# tomcat docker container stop and exit after stop tomcat server

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat8

I am using [docker container/image here](https://hub.docker.com/_/tomcat/). After running the docker container, everything is OK. but if I run `/usr/local/tomcat/bin# ./catalina.sh stop` or `/usr/local/tomcat/bin# ./shutdown.sh`, the running docker container will stop and exit.

Why? How to change it?

Thanks. Any comment welcomed.

Answer (score 7):

This is by definition, see https://github.com/docker-library/tomcat/blob/master/Dockerfile.template in which the latest line is `CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]`

Once you manually do `catalina stop` you cause the above CMD to terminate, hence the container stops.